# Physical address to an IP address

Tags: ip

I have a theoretical question here on IP's.

We all know how to do a simple trace on a IP address ether in the cmd or via a web application to find a Physical Geo location linked to that ip. My Question is can this be reversed?

For example if i know the address of my house and i am on holiday how would i find my ip?

My line of thought is that there is a massive data base of ip to Geo location can you just reverse the search ? if not why and what would be the kinda of problems to overcome. Is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can do it, because it is one-directional relationship. IP address does not depend directly on your physical location. Think about it that way: if you connect to your wifi from your neighbour's home, does it mean that your IP has changed? Your address depends on location only in the way that your ISP operates within certain area only and some IP address range is reserved for him.

In theory you could determine the IP address based on physical address if you had access to your ISP's customers database, but unless you are e.g. a police officer working on some case, you have no legal access to it.

The problems to overcome would be breaking into databases of every ISP in the world ;)

If you want to have access to your computer while on holiday, it's enough to have a static IP or use a service like dyndns.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for a grate response i kinda of expected something like that.

I have a follow up question/s:

do you think it not bean made easily available because its not "useful info" or because of technical issues (you mentioned ip not fixed by device but you could have fixed ip for each log in pipe(if that makes sense) )or privacy issues?

If it because of privacy issues i find it kind of strange as you can track people down via an IP i would have thought the same argument would hold in both courts.

Again thanks for your help.

Comment: Hard to answer this question in the comment as it is very broad. I think you should read about how the internet works in general, how IPs are resolved etc. and you should get the idea why. The short answer is: probably partially because of everything you've mentioned, but I haven't read about motivation specifically, so it's only my guess.

Comment: Haha how the internet works .... i am sure that would be a Phd there!

okay thanks for the reply its appreciated ill do some more reading on the subject.